# MySQL best practice: Updating relational tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have a main MySQL table which holds products.  Any multiple fields for each product are housed in relational tables (such as products_colour, products_photos, etc.)  Every time I update a product, I'm unsure as to what's the best practice to do:

1. `DELETE` all rows in relational tables which correspond to the product being updated, and `INSERT` all the new fields into a relatively fresh table;
2. Only `DELETE` those rows in relational tables which are no longer required, and `INSERT` the brand new rows which are not already there.

The first option blanket deletes everything and inserts fresh data every time the product is updated; the second option searches for extant values, calculates whether they clash, deletes them if so, and inserts the remaining data. Or something along those lines...

In terms of best practice, what's the best thing to do?  Does it really matter if I go with the first one?  Would it make *that* much difference to MySQL performance?

Comment: When you say "relational databases", you actually mean "related tables"

Comment: Say a product is red and yellow.  A user wants to update the product so that it is only red.  If UPDATE is only used, in the relational database housing the product's colours, the yellow row will still be there. I don't want to collect hundreds of redundant, obselete rows.

Comment: @ypercube yes, sorry - error on my part. Updated the question now.

Comment: It's a shame you couldn't use PostgreSQL's triggers. Cause, you know, those things don't work in MySQL.

Comment: "best" implies some fitness criteria. What are yours? Without them, this is an inappropriate, subjective question that should be closed.

Comment: @Kenaniah: Why would you need triggers for some Insert, Delete, Update operations?

Comment: Can you give more details about your schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "best practice" for your use-case would be to `DELETE` the old rows, then `INSERT` the new ones.  **Make sure you use [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)!**